# Annotate in SQLite

Tags: django, sqlite, django-models

I have the following model:

```
class Model(...):
  date = DateField()
  user = ForeignKey()
  data = ForeignKey()
  time = IntegerField()
```

I'd like to make sum of time field for every user for a single data, so I do:

```
Model.objects.filter(date=..., data=...).values('user_id').annotate(time=Sum('time'))
```

but I receive result which looks like:

[{'user_id': 1, 'time': 20},{'user_id': 1, 'time': 10}, {'user_id': 2, 'time': 20}]

So the grouping does not work. I checked query generated by django and I don't know why django uses date and data for grouping as well, not only user. Am I doing something wrong or this is only SQLite issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You should append `.order_by()` to your query set to clear default model ordering.**

For your code:

```
(Model.objects.filter(date=…, data=…)
              .values('user_id')
              .annotate(time=Sum('time'))
              .order_by())                        # <---- Here
```

This is full explained in [default ordering doc warning](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#interaction-with-default-ordering-or-order-by):

> "Except that it won't quite work. The default ordering by name will
>   also play a part in the grouping ... you should ... clearing any ordering in the query."

Comment: Great answer, but where did you get this wrapping from?

Comment: @KrzysiekSzularz, are you talking about code syle formatting? Yea! sorry, is for avoid scroll bars. Please, can you rewraping it better? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Put whole command in brackets and wrap after inner `)`. Do you like it better that way?

Comment: Better now!!! Thanks! My style is close to: PEP8 http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length ... in the broad sense of the 'close' word  ;)  (sorry just a joke)